# Sort by multiple columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table in which I have three fields with data type INT, INT and INT.

I want to sort my select query using all these three columns. Sort by ASC if field A <= 10, sort by DESC field2 and sort by ASC field 3.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=uid     
ORDER BY 
    CASE table1.field1
        WHEN table1.field1 < 11 THEN table1.field1
        END
    ASC, 
table1.field2 DESC,
table1.field3 ASC;

+------+--------+---------+
|field1| field2 | field3  |
+------+--------+---------+
|   1  |    4   |    1    |
+------+--------+---------+
|   2  |    3   |    2    |
+------+--------+---------+
|   9  |    2   |    4    |
+------+--------+---------+
|  10  |    1   |    7    |
+------+--------+---------+
```

For some reason the `CASE` doesnt really work, if I exclude that it works but does sort all of field1 in ASC order while I only want the 10 first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `table1.field1` before `WHEN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id = uid     
ORDER BY CASE WHEN table1.field1 < 11 THEN table1.field1 END ASC, 
  table1.field2 DESC,
  table1.field3 ASC;
```

---

Explanation:

```
CASE table1.field1
     WHEN table1.field1 < 11 THEN table1.field1
END       -- this evaluates to true/false (1 and 0)

=>
CASE table1.field1 WHEN 1 THEN table1.field1 END
```

Comment: While the order now is correct, for some reason those 10 rows, are ordered as should be, but appear to be the last 10 rows that I get, instead of the top 10.

Comment: @JohnJames `while I only want the 10 first.` It looks like you need `LIMIT 10` then. If not then your question is probably n-values-per-group so I would suggest to ask another question with http://rextester.com sample data and desired resultset.